# Create a Network Drive Invisible to Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, shared-folders

I want to create a shared folder in Linux that's inaccessible/invisible to Windows users, how would I do this? It needs to have basic security, so somebody using Linux who would join my network can't access it without my permission.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Do you want it visible anywhere? Is it only being 'invisible' that you want, or do users not need access also? You have tagged Ubuntu; is it on a linux platform that the folder is created? Is there any other research you have found similar to this?

Comment: Provided more information.

Comment: What devices WOULD be accessing it? It seems you want a shared folder but not accessible to Windows devices but you also don't want untrusted Linux devices to have access? The native sharing protocol for Linux if NFS (resolves your Windows problem) so you should use this but employ ACLs (resolves your "untrusted" devices issue): http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/ACLs

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general rule of thumb, defined shares, where the names end with a $, will be hidden from file explorer. **You must set the name of the share to end with the $ in the configuration file of the program otherwise it will not work.**

Plus, security by obscurity is not real security and you will need to configure your share with authentication if you want to keep out prying eyes.

However, it's difficult to fully answer your question because we don't know what protocol you're using on your Linux machine to share your folders. Let us know if you're using Samba, or NFS, or whatever so we can better help you.

Comment: I'm actually LOOKING for a protocol to use. I want to stray away from Samba, because that has compatibility with Windows. I'm going to assume SOME protocols have compatibility with Windows, so the easier it is to make the protocol compatible with Windows, the less I want to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a file sharing protocol that is only compatible with Linux, because technically, NFS and Samba are both "compatible" with Windows. I'm not too savvy on NFS shares, but I do know how to setup Samba so the share is hidden and requires authentication to access the share.

Comment: If it's the only option that meets my criteria (excluding some) then I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: Here's what you need to know. The server is still "accessible" as it can be seen on the network tab of File Explorer if the Windows computer has network discovery and file sharing turned on. If the user runs "net view \\yourServer /all" on the command prompt, they will see all of your shares, including hidden shares, on the command prompt window only. However, if you have proper security set on the share, they cannot see the files in the share without a username and password. So, you will need to be careful what you name the shares, and will need to make sure that authentication is set up.

Comment: I do need to know a few things from you. Are you fine with the limitations of what I outlined in the previous comment for setting up Samba? What operating system, and version, are you using? Is this on your home network, or what? Are you trying to share folders from the hard drive on the server, or an external drive? Other question may come to mind, but those seem to be on the fore front of my brain at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

How about choosing another protocol that windoze users are unlikely to have installed?

For example AFP can be installed under linux, and if you get your linux machines all set up with AFP, the winzode boxes should be frozen out.

There's a guide to installing AFP here:

https://www.outcoldman.com/en/archive/2014/11/09/ubuntu-as-home-server-part-3-afp-server/